# Activity Ciclo de Vida + system.currentTimeMillis()

Tags: android, android-activity

Essa atividade é sobre ciclo de vida em Android, eu li diversos materiais porem continuo perdido? Alguém pode explicar por favor.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que você não entendeu?

Comment: Não estou sabendo aplicar uma logica para pegar o tempo parada e o tempo pausado, como aplica o TimeMillis?

Comment: O System.currentTimeMillis() retorna um número que representa a data e hora atual em milissegundos (tipo, quantos milissegundos se passaram desde a data padrão, acho que 1/1/1970, até agora), então você salva numa váriável, por exemplo "tempoInicial = System.currentTimeMillis()". Quando você quiser medir o tempo passado desde o tempo inicial, você vai chamar o currentTimeMillis de novo, que vai gerar um número maior que o primeiro e vai pegar a diferença entre eles (em milissegundos), depois só converter pra unidade que você quiser (minutos, segundos, etc)

Comment: Entendi a ideia de pegar o tempo inicial e calcular.

Comment: Pode dar um exemplo de implementação mesmo basica? e o contador funciona como dentro do onStop, onStart...?

Comment: protected void onStart(){                                                                                                   super.onStart();                                    system.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()); } No caso ele tem que ser exibido em um TextView

Answer (score 0):

Dê uma olhada aqui: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/system_currenttimemillis.htm

Explica em mais detalhes o que citei no meu último comentário. Mas basicamente a lógica é você usar o System.currentTimeMillis() para ir salvando marcos de tempo que você vai querer medir: quando a Activity inicia, quando ela pausa, etc.

Prá medir o tempo passado entre esses marcos, basta pegar a diferença entre eles, que será um valor em milissegundos, então só converter para a unidade que você quer (minutos, segundos, etc).

Comment: No caso isso é pra java puro, mas pode implementar no android da mesma forma?

Comment: Rodrigo, você está com dúvidas muito básicas. Acho que você vai ter muita dificuldade em aprender a programar Android dessa forma, só fazendo perguntas por aqui. Eu sugiro fortemente que você dê uma estudada. Eu comecei ano passado por esse curso, que é oficial da Google, e me ajudou muito. Não é grande e está legendado em português: https://br.udacity.com/course/android-development-for-beginners--ud837/